# Solidifying knowledge of javascript objects, methods, and properties

Tags: javascript, object, methods, properties

I just want to solidify(know for sure) what are js objects, methods and properties. This is by far my own perspective but I have few doubts and that is why I am here to know and certify what I need is true.

```
var property= "is this a property?";
function method(){"is this a method?"};
var ObjectLiteral = {property:"this should be a property of this ObjectLiteral I guess", method:function(){"this should be a method of ObjectLiteral am I right?"}};

//Here is the cache:

var Cachie = {method : function SecondObject(){/*nothing in here just a regular function or object*/},objecto:function(){alert("is this a method or object of Cachie object if so methods and properties are functions and variables")}};
Cachie.objecto();//than what is objecto related to Cachie and what is objecto called related Cachie is it an object of Cachie by the way, or is just simply called an object and nothing else of Cachie whatsoever?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact in Javascript an object literal is a list of zero or more pairs of property names and associated values of an object, enclosed in curly braces ({}).

You can take a look at [**The MDN Specification for Object Literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) for further information.

And in your case if you write:

```
var Cachie = {method : function SecondObject(){/*nothing in here just a regular function or object*/},objecto:function(){alert("is this a method or object of Cachie object if so methods and properties are functions and variables")}};
Cachie.objecto();
```

Means that:

You have a literal object called `Cachie` with two properties: `method` and `objecto`, which are functions here so to answer your question ***what is objecto related to Cachie?***, `objecto` is a function and a property of the `Cachie` object.

So when you call `Cachie.objecto()` you are simply calling the function hold in the property `objecto` of the Object `Cachie`.

Comment: One more thing which I'm confused that needs to get out of the way, are methods commands built-in mostly or there are custom methods(not just as identifier)?

Comment: Sorry to bother there is a list of all methods in MDN.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it? What do you mean by that?

Comment: MDN mentions that it has a list of all methods on their documentation, perhaps at the time I wrote the comment I thought MDN mentioned all the methods there is, which now I might not be sure which is true(not taking in consideration of the ever changing web)?

Comment: Do you mean the **Methods** in their documentation like `hasOwnProperty()`, `propertyIsEnumerable()` .... ?

Comment: Yes, although I figured it's possible to customize just as well. All there needs to be done is something like: 
function i(){return "this is a custom method of window object and string of the function here in and i identifier which is a object(the function)"}; window.i(); // am I correct this time?

Comment: It will be `window.i();`or simply use directly `i();`.

Comment: Even though simply : 
i() //is it still a method of the window object?

Comment: Yes it is, in fact in javascript when you declare a function in the global scope (not in any object or function) it will be hold in the `window` object as it is the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variable

`var property`

This is a function declaration

`function method() { };`

This is a variable of type object (declared in JSON format), with 2 properties.

```
var obj = {
    property: "", 
    method: function() {}
};
```

The same thing can be written like this, which is of course not JSON:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.property = "";
obj.method = function() {};
```

Or

```
var obj = new function() {
    this.property = "";
    this.method = function() {};
}
```

Etc, there are other ways as well.

Your other examples are the same as above, e.g., calling `obj.method()`. `method` is a member of `obj`, which is an object, and the member is of type `function`. You can test this by calling `typeof(obj.method)` and it should return `'function'`.